# How can I access to WebElement's son in Selenium?

Tags: html, css, selenium

'''
page_bar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')
'''

[tr]

[div][/div]

[div][/div]

[div][/div]

[div][/div]

[/tr]
Like this...

I used this code to take WebElement. And, I want to sort page_bar's son's text. Is there any function that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Jongmin Ahn you can try the following:

```
# First get all the child elements of page bar in a list:
all_child_element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr>div")

# Get all the text in another list
all_child_element_text = [] # Declaring empty list
for one_child in all_child_element:
    all_child_element_text.append(one_child.text)

# Now sort
all_child_element_text.sort()
```